# Peach fuzzer. Create docx and fuzzing ms-word

Tags: fuzzing, peach

By means of such pit-file I can generate [Content_Types].xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Peach xmlns="http://peachfuzzer.com/2012/Peach" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://peachfuzzer.com/2012/Peach ../peach.xsd">

    <!-- Define our file format DDL -->
    <DataModel name="TestTemplate">
        <XmlElement elementName="Types" ns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">

            <XmlElement elementName="Default">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="Extension">
                        <String value="png">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="image/png">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Default">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="Extension">
                        <String value="emf">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="image/x-emf">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Default">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="Extension">
                        <String value="rels">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Default">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="Extension">
                        <String value="xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Default">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="Extension">
                        <String value="vsdx">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.ms-visio.drawing">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Default">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="Extension">
                        <String value="wdp">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="image/vnd.ms-photo">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>

            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/document.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/numbering.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/styles.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/settings.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/webSettings.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/footnotes.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footnotes+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/endnotes.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.endnotes+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/header1.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/fontTable.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/word/theme/theme1.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/docProps/core.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
            <XmlElement elementName="Override">
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="PartName">
                        <String value="/docProps/app.xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
                <XmlAttribute attributeName="ContentType">
                        <String value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml">
                        <Analyzer class="StringToken"/>
                        </String>
                </XmlAttribute>
            </XmlElement>
        </XmlElement>
    </DataModel>

    <!-- Define a simple state machine that will write the file and 
        then launch a program using the FileWriter and DebuggerLaucher publishers -->
    <StateModel name="State" initialState="Initial">
        <State name="Initial">

            <!-- Write out contents of file.  The publisher attribute matches 
            the name we provide for the publisher in the Test section. -->
            <Action type="output">
                <DataModel ref="TestTemplate" />
            </Action>

            <!-- Close file -->
            <Action type="close" />

            <!-- <Action ty -->

            <!-- Launch the file consumer -->
            <Action type="call" method="ScoobySnacks" publisher="Peach.Agent"/>

        </State>
    </StateModel>

    <!-- Setup a local agent that will monitor for faults -->
    <Agent name="LocalAgent">
        <!-- <Monitor class="RunCommand">
        <Param name="Command" value="ping google.ru" />
        </Monitor> -->
        <Monitor class="WindowsDebugger">

            <Param name="CommandLine" value="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe fuzzfile.bin" />
            <Param name="WinDbgPath" value="C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\" />

            <Param name="StartOnCall" value="ScoobySnacks" />

        </Monitor>

        <!-- Enable heap debugging on our process as well. -->
        <Monitor class="PageHeap">
            <!-- <Param name="Executable" value="notepad.exe"/> -->
            <Param name="Executable" value="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe"/>
            <Param name="WinDbgPath" value="C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\" />
        </Monitor>
    </Agent>

    <Test name="Default">
        <Agent ref="LocalAgent" />
        <StateModel ref="State"/>

        <!-- Configure our publisher with correct filename to write too -->
        <Publisher class="File">
            <Param name="FileName" value="fuzzfile.bin" />
        </Publisher>

        <!-- Configure a logger to store collected information -->
        <Logger class="Filesystem">
            <Param name="Path" value="logtest" />
        </Logger>
    </Test>

</Peach>
<!-- end -->
```

By means of such command I can create docx:

```
C:\peach>"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip fuzz.docx _rels\* docProps\* word [Content_Types].xml
```

How can I create archive from [Content_Types].xml and rest of files using peach and then open it with ms-word?

I need to track(trace) craches of ms-word

Comment: I found [GzipCompressTransformer](http://community.peachfuzzer.com/v3/Transformers/GzipCompressTransformer.html) But I can pack only described in DataModel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Monitor class="Process"`

```
<Agent name="LocalAgent">

        <Monitor class="Process">
            <Param name="Executable" value="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" />
            <Param name="Arguments" value="a -tzip myfuzz.docx C:\peach\_rels C:\peach\docProps C:\peach\word [Conntent_Types].xml" />
        </Monitor>

........
</Agent>
```

But for peach v3.1 release it is recommended to use RunCommand